# Primefaces inputText Ajax, retorna valor faltando o último caracter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou com com um problema usando o *ajax* do *primefaces*, tentei também com o *ajax* do *jsf*.
Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<h:panelGroup>
  <p:inputText id="skuProduto" size="20" maxlength="20"
    value="#{cadastroProdutoPapBean.produto.sku}"
    validator="#{cadastroProdutoPapBean.validaProduto}">
       <p:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" update="mesSkuProduto, teste"/>
  </p:inputText>
  <p:message display="text" for="skuProduto" style="color:red"
                        id="mesSkuProduto" rendered="true" />
 <h:outputText id="teste"value="Aqui o teste do que foi digitado: #{cadastroProdutoPapBean.produto.sku}" style="color:red"></h:outputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Testei usando:

```
p:ajax event="keyup"
p:ajax event="blur"
```

E nas duas situações ao trazer o valor digitado para o método ele fica faltando o último caracter
Exemplo do retorno:

```
Valor do sku digitado: 33221
```

Coloquei um outputText no trecho apresentado para verificar o que estava sendo impresso e retorna o valor correto. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso, e teria uma solução pra esse problema?

Estou usando no meu bean *@ViewScoped* e busco o valor digitado com:

```
System.out.println("Valor do sku digitado: " + produto.getSku());
```

Comment: Coloca o código do MBean então, que está trazendo sem o último dígito.

Comment: Meu bean é bem grande, então coloquei as informações relevantes do bean.

Comment: Onde está inserido o system out que imprime o valor com um dígito a menos? Coloca o contexto em que ele está inserido.

Comment: Olá Giuliana, consegui resolver o problema, achava que era na página jsf mas na verdade era no método, bobeira que estava fazendo. Vou fazer uma resposta com a solução.

Comment: Por isso precisava do post do mbean, entende? Só com o que você expôs na tua pergunta não dava pra saber o problema. Coloca o código do MBean na pergunta.

Comment: Olá Giuliana, obrigada pelo interesse em ajudar, como achava não ser um problema no método e por ele conter muita informação achei que não havia necessidade, engano meu. Mas na resposta especifiquei o problema e a solução!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue solução caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema. Acontece que estava usando um método com evento e fazendo a chamada da seguinte forma:

```
public void verificar(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String valor = produto.getSku();
    System.out.println("Valor do sku digitado: " + valor);
    ...
}
```

Quando iniciei o processo de validação dos dados mudei meu método para:

```
 public void validaProduto(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object value) { 
    String valor = produto.getSku();
    System.out.println("Valor do sku digitado: " + valor);
    ...
 }
```

Aí que esta o problema, pois ao usar o *validator* do *inputText* eu tenho o valor do *Object value* e não de uma *String* com o valor do *get* declarado, pois para as funcionalidades do método *Validate* funcionar de forma correta, o valor retornado pelo método tem que ser o valor do *Object value*. Segue abaixo como ficou a parte que recebe o valor vindo da página:

```
public void validaProduto(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object value) {
  String valor = (String) value;
  System.out.println("Valor do sku digitado: " + valor);
  ...
}
```